# Parallel loop with one list literal

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to loop over two lists, one being a premade list and one being a list literal. Is something like this possible?

Pseudocode example:

```
list(list1 APPEND 0 1 2 3 4)

foreach(item IN LISTS ${list1} 5 6 7 8 9)
    message(${item} ${#other variable})  
endforeach(item)

# prints out 

0 5
1 6
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

For iterate over several lists at the same time, you may use `foreach` loop over their *indicies*. Then, in the loop body access the lists's elements by that index:

```
# Setup content of the lists somehow
set(list1 0 1 2 3 4)
set(list2 5 6 7 8 9)

list(LENGTH list1 n_elems) # Total number of the elements in the every list
math(EXPR last_index "${n_elems}-1") # The last index in the every list

# Now iterate over indicies
foreach(i RANGE ${last_index})
    list(GET list1 ${i} elem1) # Element in the first list
    list(GET list2 ${i} elem2) # Corresponded element in the second list
    # Do something with elements
    message("${elem1} ${elem2}")
endforeach()
```